# Emacs freezes when using Ivy or Helm with Dired

Tags: emacs, ivy, freeze, emacs-helm

I'm using Emacs on windows 10.
When i use Dired I can open (`C-x C-f`) files without any problems.
But when I use helm or ivy for opening files, it gets really slow and takes more than 10 sec to change a directory. And when I want to change partition, it freezes.

This is what i get when I profile for CPU and memory:
[cpu and memory profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf5P4.png)

This is my Emacs config, maybe there is something wrong that I don't see.
`emacs config` [emacs config](https://pastebin.com/G2kFdL7f)
I dont know how to go on from there. Maybe you guys can offer some help?